# How can I get the "My Music" folder back in Windows 7 after deleting it?

Tags: windows-7

I don't know why, but I deleted the `My Music` folder in the `My Documents` directory  It's not in the Recycling Bin, and I didn't have anything in it as yet, but would like to get it back.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to get the folder back?

Answer (score 3):

Amanda, you wrote:

> I deleted the "my music" folder from
> my documents. Its not in the recycling
> bin.

You also say that you have Windows 7. This strikes me as a bit odd, as the "My Music" folder is not in the "My Documents" folder, but at the same level. In other words, assuming that your Windows username is amanda, then you should see two folders with the path:

> C:\Users\amanda\Music
>
> C:\Users\amanda\Documents

I suspect that what you've actually done is to remove the "My Music" entry from the Libraries hierarchy in the Windows Explorer. This doesn't put any folders into the Recycle Bin, it just deletes the entry from the Libraries.

To put it back, just right-click on the Music library icon, choose Properties, and in the Properties window click the "Include a folder..." button to include C:\Users\amanda\Music back into the Library view.